# sails model is getting unrecognized datastore error on nested await method call

Tags: sails.js

I just cant figure out why this fails where it does.
This code is in a sails model called in Job.js
The Init() is called from bootstrap.js
This is all based on the ORM adapter sails-disk.

```
Init: async function() {
    _jobRunner();
},
_jobRunner: function() {
    async function doJobRunner() {
        let job = await Job.findOne({state: 'inactive'});
        let updated = await Job.Update(job);
    }
    setInterval(doJobRunner,3000);
},

Update: async function(job) {
    let query = {id:job.id}
    let updates,updated;
    try {
        let origJob = await Job.findOne(query);    <-- success
        updates = {status: 'active'}  <-- added for illustration
        updated = await Job.updateOne(query).set(updates);  <----- this fails into catch (why?)
        Job.publish(job.id,updated);    // notify
    } catch(err) {
        sails.log.error(err);
    }
    return updated;
},
```

```
the Error is (err):
Unexpected error from database adapter: Unrecognized datastore: `default`,  It doesn't seem to have been registered with this adapter (sails-disk).'
modelIdentity:'job'


**Node version**:  v14.17.4
**Sails version** _(sails)_: 1.4.4
**ORM hook version** _(sails-hook-orm)_: 3.0.2
**sails-disk**_: 2.1.0
```

Comment: I encountered a similar issue (nondeterministically), even without a nested function, when fetching data from a handler of the Sails "lifted" event. It looks like for whatever reason, sails-disk doesn't always have the datastores registered (yet) at the moment Sails lifts, so adding some kind of delay might solve it.